# Zsh: manually load completion functions

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

If I load completion functions at shell startup, but I spawn shell like a madman to work on the same folder.

This is the case when I have multiple completion functions that target repository that contain `.git` folder, if we're in repo then the functions are loaded.

Problem is that with all completion functions start when spawn new shell, it draw shell prompt quite slow.

So how to manually trigger to load/`source` completion functions? Even I know I already in `.git` repo, I still want manually load completion function before use it, the cost of slow shell spawn is higher than the completion itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of loading completion functions at startup, declare them as autoloaded. This way each function will be loaded the first time it is used.

The normal way to do this is to put the code of each function into a file in a directory on `$fpath`. Call the file with the name you want to give to the function. On the first line of the file, add a [`#compdef` tag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Autoloaded-files).

So if you used to have this in your `.zshrc`:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit -u
_foo () {
  code goes here
}
compdef _foo foo
```

then, instead, only put this in your `.zshrc`:

```
fpath=(~/.zsh/functions $fpath)
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit -u
```

and create `~/.zsh/functions/_foo` containing

```
#compdef foo
code goes here
```

Comment: So each time I want to use the `_foo` function I have to issue this command `autoload -Uz _foo`? If yes, is there a way to map to a combined key to call it faster?

Comment: @TuyenPham You don't need an explicit `autoload` statement if the function is in a file in `$fpath` when you run `compinit` and the file starts with a `#compdef` or `#autoload` line.

Comment: In a general file named `utils.zsh`, can I have multiple `#compdef foo` and later `compdef bar` in the same `utils.zsh` file? I want to have ony one file for multiple small utils.

Comment: @TuyenPham You can have multiple names after `#compdef`, but that gives you one function that's used to complete multiple commands. You can't put multiple functions in the same file (except auxiliary functions for the main function, but only the main function gets autoloaded).